# Pass type of current class/object to a generic method without explicit type reference in C# program?

Tags: c#, generics, types

Is there a short hand for the type of the current class/object that I can use when calling a generic method, instead of having to explicitly pass the name of the current class/object?

For example, given the sample code below:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        // Call some generic method that returns a string.
        string s = GenMeth<SomeClass>)();
    }
} // public class SomeClass
```

Is there a way to tell C# that I want to pass the class of the current class (SomeClass) to GenMeth() without having to explicitly say *SomeClass*?

A hypothetical and bogus example that illustrates the concept:

```
string s = GenMeth<GetType(this)>();
```

Comment: @mbeckish That question is a little too different to be a duplicate in my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

If you make your method consume an instance of that type, it can infer it.  For example, if your method looked like:

```
void GenMeth<T>(T instance) {}
```

Then you could invoke it like:

```
GenMeth(this);
```

Whether this would be acceptable to you might be a different story.  (it would be a bit weird if you never consumed the argument)

Comment: If you do end up doing this, provide it as an optional overload rather than the only one, so that you can use it when you don't have an instance of the type you want the generic argument to be.

Comment: @Servy, definitely.  Honestly I couldn't see myself using this solution, but thought it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such syntax.

You could, in theory, call the method via reflection, thus allowing you to use `this.GetType()`, but that would make things much, much worse for you.  Just...don't do that.  It's *much* easier to just remember to change the generic argument to the current type if you copy/paste the code.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the type of the current class may not be the same as the type of the current object.  If the class is subclassed `this.GetType()` could return a different type than the current class.

Comment: @jam40jeff Not when it's called from a constructor ;)

Comment: It's late and I may be missing something, but couldn't the constructor being executed be a base constructor call from a subclass?  In that case, the code would be executing in the superclass, but `this.GetType()` would return the subclass, right?

Comment: @jam40jeff Oh, you are correct, nevermind me.  It would need to be in a static method.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an extension method that performs whatever your operation is on any object.  You can check in the extension method for types that are legitimate using `GetType()`.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions {

  public static string GenMeth(this object obj) {
    // do stuff here and return string type
  }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is relevant to the question.