# How can I pass current class type into <T>?

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

I have a attribute class (inheriting Attribute), inside which I have a method which calls a generic method:

```
memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<T>();
```

How can I pass current class type into T? I don't want to hard type the class name inside as it may be inherited and then it will not work.

Comment: You can use interface

Comment: What interface? @Jimbot

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781882/pass-type-of-current-class-object-to-a-generic-method-without-explicit-type-refe

Answer (score 5):

You can use the version that takes `Type`, not the generic version :

```
memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType());
```

Answer (score -1):

below should work :

```
memberinfo.GetType().GetMethod("GetCustomAttribute").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(instance, new object[] { 'yourMethodParameter'} )
```

Comment: `memberInfo` is not `YourType`.

Comment: This is overly complicated if you can just drop the type argument as in the other answer.

Comment: This is an option for generic methods that do not offer non-generic versions, in this case we have a perfectly good non-generic version is defined (my guess is that the generic version is just a wrapper over the non-generic one)